# centered circular image with css

Tags: html, css

I'm having this code to create a circular image with css

```
  <div class="round2">
    <img src="http://fwncwww14.wks.gorlaeus.net/images/home/news/mbt_pasfoto_Dino_van_Dissel.jpg" />
  </div>

.round2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.round2 img {
    display: block;
    /* Stretch
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%; */
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Now I would like to be the circle in the middle of the image instead of the top position of the image.. Does anyone of you know how to achieve this?

Thanks very much !

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? It's kinda hard to understand what you mean

Comment: add your HTML please

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Elvira You can always use a SO snippet, it's the document with the `<>` in it :)

Answer (score 2):

Just move it away by `50%` and then `transform` it back `50%`, like this:

```css
.round2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.round2 img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /* use `calc(50%)` if you want to be old-browser safe */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    /* Be sure to prefix where necessary */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="round2"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" /></div>
```

Now just position the outer `.round2` class box to move your image around. This works because the `translate` function relates to the `img` elements `width`, and not the parent containers'.

Comment: Does it always need to be a square image?

Comment: It changes back to a square.. instead of a circle.

Comment: No it will work either way. The positioning pushes it to themiddle, the translate pushes it back by half, so it is centred.

Comment: It still changes back to a square :P it's a circle at first.. and than after a view seconds it's a square..

Comment: No idea, isn't happening on my end.. Borderradius and overflow should have taken care of that...

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to your `.round2` class.

```css
.round2 {
    display: block; /* or inline-block */
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```